# Solve for an expression, given its relationship with its derivative

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

I was wondering if given $F(x)= f(x) - x,$  (Where $F(x)$ is anti derivative of $f(x)$) is it possible to find expressions for $F(x).$ Is there only one solution, or many? Is it even possible? Thank you. Everything I’ve tried has been useless,I don’t even know which direction to go in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $F(x)$ denote? Is it an antiderivative of $f$?

Comment: @AlannRosas Yes sorry, i will edit post

Comment: @AlannRosas I see that originally I may have implied double derivative, in F(x) —> f ‘ (x) .  This was not the intended case.

Comment: What you have is an ordinary differential equation for $F$. It is linear, there are standard techniques to solve it, integrating factors for ex. There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: specifically, it is a linear first-order differential equation, which can be solved fairly straightforwardly once you know the techniques! some googling should show loads of resources, as this is a very common situation to be in. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then we can write $f(x)=F'(x)$, so the given condition is equivalent to $F(x)=F'(x)-x$, or $F'(x)-F(x)=x$. This is a first-order linear differential equation that can be solved by multiplication with a suitable integrating factor, namely $e^{-x}$. This gives

$$e^{-x}F'(x)-e^{-x}F(x)=xe^{-x}$$

Notice that the left side is simply $\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}F(x)\right)$. Thus,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}F(x)\right)=xe^{-x}$$

or

$$e^{-x}F(x)=\int xe^{-x} dx=-e^{-x}(1+x)+C$$

Multiplying through by $e^x$ gives $F(x)=Ce^x-1-x$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, I see what the others meant by linear now